# Rebol 3 - R3-GUI - How to access text from an area?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

I'm struggling a lot coming from R2 and dealing with faces.   get-facet seems extremely unintuitive to me.

Let's say I have an area:

```
view [c: area "hello"] print get-facet c 'text-edit
```

`get-facet` always returns `"hello"` even if I type something else in the area.  What is going on with this?  The `'caret` and `'state` facet objects contain the correct text, but I cannot find a way to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is `get-face`.  Get facet should be used for

For the example above, it is fixed by:

```
view [c: area "hello"] print get-face c
```

From an explanation from Cyphre:  `get-face` is intended for the application programmers but `get-facet` is intended for style developers because it directly accesses the style internals.  If styles are updated it may break code if `get-face` is not used.   One should avoid using refinements such as /text or /data on faces as it was easy to do in R2

AREA's facet TEXT-EDIT looks like it just stores the initialization, and the state/caret facet objects contain run-time data

Comment: Although, I still do not understand why there wouldn't be an easy get-facet option (if there isn't)